# Kotlin: Generic Collection to Generic Array

Tags: arrays, generics, collections, kotlin

How to get a generic [array](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) out of a generic [collection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-collection/index.html)?

I have done the following:

```
val genericArray: Array<E> = (genericCollection as java.util.Collection<E>).toArray() as Array<E>
```

Is this the right way to go or is there a more elegant solution?

Looking forward to your help!

**EDIT**

I ended up writing this helper extension:

```
fun <E> Collection<E>.toUntypedArray(): Array<E> {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return arrayOf(size, this) as Array<E>
}
```

Does anyone of you have a better solution for this problem?

Comment: what is the problem with ```public actual inline fun <reified T> Collection<T>.toTypedArray(): Array<T>``` ?

Comment: Would that do the trick? `listOf("one", "two").toTypedArray<Any>()` If not I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve here...

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to cast it to Java Collection.

```
fun example () {
    val collection: Collection<Int> = listOf()
    val typeArray = collection.toTypedArray()
}

fun <T> example2(collection: Collection<T>) {
    val typeArray = arrayof(collection)
}
```

Comment: But that's the problem. toTypedArray() is a reified function and can't take a generic as input.

Comment: this doesn't work either, because the returns a Array<Collection<E>> and not Array<E>

Comment: You could solve the `Array<Collection<E>>` problem with the spread operator: `arrayOf(*collection.toTypedArray())`